# Mac making clicking (?) sound after dropping

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an early 2015 macbook pro. Purchased it in September 2016. I dropped it several times (on carpet) that year, and got a few dents on the edges/corners of my macbook. I don't recall dropping it from 2017 until yesterday, where my mac fell off my bed (2 feet up) onto my wooden floor. I didn't notice any new dents, and the Mac works normally.

But during the day today, my Mac occasionally made this subtle clicking sound. At the time, I actually thought it was maybe something in my house making the sound. It came randomly and intermittently so I couldn't tell where it was coming from. It's been making that clicking/popping sound consistently for the past 2 hours, and I'm positive it's coming from my Mac now. It's not loud.

I also have a deteriorated battery. It's currently saying "service battery," and I've had this warning for the past year. I'm at about 950 cycles. The warning started showing up around 850 cycles. Not sure if this has anything to do with the popping sound.

My guess is the popping sound is because of me dropping it. Has anyone had experience with this and can shed some light on what I should do to determine what's causing the sound, and how to fix it?

Here's a recording of the sound using my iPhone https://vocaroo.com/52ZuEVUFrJs. Note it probably sounds louder in the video than it actually does and that's because I put my iPhone right next to where the sound is coming from.

Comment: A recording of the popping/clicking would be helpful.  It could be anything from the speakers, to the fan, or even the logic board.  But without  actually hearing it, its impossible to know. I also advice getting the battery replaced (if you plan to keep it).  As problems compound, it becomes mor and more difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Allan I'll figure out how to upload the recording and link it here. I was leaning towards geting the battery replaced, but if me dropping the mac broke something serious, then I may opt to not replace the battery and eventually get a new mac.

Comment: @Allan Here's a recording. https://vocaroo.com/52ZuEVUFrJs

Comment: That *sounds* like it *might* be a spinning hard drive clicking. If there is a spinning HD in this Mac, back it up now and replace it. Failing that it could be a fan.

Comment: @SteveChambers I have a 256 GB SSD, so I don't think that's the issue. Also, I just ran the hardware diagnostic test before starting up and the only issue that I saw was the battery issue. If I bring this in to an Apple store, will the techs there be able to run other diagnostics that I can't run myself?

Comment: Yes. Apple will be able to diagnose this and likely repair it. Note, fully back up your Mac and set a special temporary admin login for the Apple techs. That gives them access to the Mac but not your files.